# Merge user accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts

I heard that moderators can merge user accounts. Should this be true I like to request the merge [user823](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/823/user823) with [frank](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3860/frank). The first one includes all the activities of this user but the second one is connected to his other SO/SX accounts. In [the comments to this questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12162/how-to-switch-from-using-color-graphics-to-grayscale-graphics) he suggest the creation of the *user823* account is a SX bug, i.e. somehow this account didn't got connected to his other accounts on creation.

Comment: The quickest way to resolve that problem is usually to flag for moderator attention. Usually they are pretty fast in responding to that (when they aren't asleep).

Comment: @Caramdir: you mean on the above linked question? I was thinking about that, but then went for this post.

Comment: In the end you have to ask the mods what they prefer (in case you don't get elected). I used a flag for this purpose a few days ago and at worked well. Flagging does have the advantage of not producing additional meta posts. Though the meta post has the advantage of educating people that this sort of thing is possible.

Comment: @Caramdir: Yes, that was the struggle I had. And therefore I was searching for such a meta thread where I could simply add me request as "answer", knowing the bumped up "question" would get notices by at least one moderator. Maybe future requests like this can be attached to this one.

Comment: I actually have the same issue here, I had answered a question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13785/modify-moderncv-header). It's the second answer user [Vagelis Bebelis](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9414/vagelis-bebelis). Later though, I created another account because for some reason I could not access the first one and I have a separate [profile](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14659/vagelis-bebelis). Can you guys merge these together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I merged the two accounts to [Frank](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3860/frank).

Comment: Thanks you, Stefan!

Comment: @MartinScharrer Could you also merge my accounts--There are two other Abhimanyu Arora's and both are mine (had forgotten passwords)